# Variable that have one of the types of an interface?

Tags: typescript

I was wondering; is something like this possible ?

```js
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

// The syntax User['*'] doesn't exist, this is just an example
const user: User['*'] = 'Bob'; // No error
const user: User['*'] = 32; // No error
const user: User['*'] = true; // Error
```

I know about the "or" (`|`), but this can become really redondent if the `User` interface has a lot of typed properties.

Comment: Are you looking for `keyof`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an indexed type query with `keyof T` to get a union of all possible values in an interface:

```
interface User {
   name: string;
   age: number;
}

const userValue1: User[keyof User] = 'Bob'; // No error
const userValue2: User[keyof User] = 32; // No error
const userValue3: User[keyof User] = true; // Error
```

If you use this a lot, a helper type might help:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]
```

Comment: There must be a dupe for this by now, no?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yup jcalz had an answer for this one ..

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes it apparently is. 
Titian thanks your for the answer, and sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there .. i killed the joy 